# Laravel 5.1 eloquent query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have the following model relationships. If a user logs in as an employee, I want them to be able to get a list of employees for a their company and the roles they have been assigned:

```
class User {

   // A user can be of an employee user type
   public function employee()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Employee');
   }

   // 
   public function roles()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
   }

 }

 class Employee {

    // employee profile belong to a user
    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // employee belongs to a company
    public function company()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
 }


 class Company {

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee'); 
    }
 }
```

But the following query doesnt work. I get error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column companies.id in WHERE clause`:

```
    $employee = Auth::user()->employee;

    $companyEmployees = Company::with(['employees.user.roles' => function ($query) use ($employee) {
        $query->where('companies.id', '=', $employee->company_id)
              ->orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc');
     }])->get();
```

The users and the employees table have a one to one relationship.
All employees have a base role type of `employee` in addition they may also have other roles such as `manager`, `supervisor` etc.

How do I write a query that gives me a company with all its employees and their roles?

I've tried to add a hasManyThrough relation to the Company model but that doesn't work either?

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Employee');
}
```

Comment: You already have roles as declared function, why you override it in your $users query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're ring to get a list of coworkers for the current user and eager load the user and role?

```
$employee = Auth::user()->employee;
$companyEmployees = Company::with(['employees.user.roles')->find($employee->company_id);
```

Or perhaps:

```
$companyEmployees = Company::find($employee->company_id)->employees()->with('user.roles')->get();
$sorted = $companyEmployees->sortBy(function($employee){ return $employee->user->created_at; });
```

That might be a more direct route. Is your employee id in the user table or vice versa? The eloquent relationships are easy to set backwards.

Comment: The second method is good. But how can you order it as employee.created_at desc?

Comment: You can sort the collection with a call back. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
Users::select('table_users.id')->with('roles')->join('table_employes', function($join) use ($employee) {

    $join->on('table_employes.user_id','=','table_users.id')->where('table_employes.company_id', '=', $employee->company_id);

})->orderBy('tables_users.created_at')->get();
```

Comment: Employee model doesn't have a relationship with roles. It is the User model which has relationship with roles so how can you eager load roles with Employee model? You would need to nest it as follows `with('user.roles')->get()`

Comment: How would you apply the orderby?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the order thing. table_employees.user_id and tables_users.id MUST be of same field data type;

Answer (score -1):

**1. Create relationship for database table columns in migrtaion :**

*User Role*

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

*Users*

```
$table->increments('id');
```

**2. Create a model for each database table to define relationship**

User.php (model)

```
    public function userRoles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserRoles', 'user_id', 'id');

    }
```

Userroles.php (model)

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

**3. Let controller handle database calls recommended to use REST api**

*Controller*

```
    use App\User;
    use App\UserRoles;

 class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
        {
            return User::with('userRoles')->orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc')->paginate(50);
        }
}
```